# USB max devices for host and hub

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I am new to USB. I am studying the [USB in a Nutshell Guide](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml) and the relevant parts of the USB2.0 spec.

As per what I have read, a max of 127 devices can be connected to a single bus. As only one host can be connected to a bus (save the on-the-go spec), I take it that 127 devices can be connected to a host.

However, on reading the [WikiPedia page for USB Hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub), it is written that a hub can extend the USB network to a max of 127 ports.

Does this mean that I can then have 127 x 127 devices attached to a single USB bus (read host)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. 127 peripheral devices on a single host. By "extend the usb network" it means that a hub takes a single upstream port, and extends it to 2~7 (typical, some hubs can do more by having multiple hub ICs) downstream ports. It still has a maximum of 127 on the bus.